# Combine Slick Slider with Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, .net, bootstrap-4, slick.js

I have this next issue in which I am having quite a significant problem.
First of all, I am trying to integrate three `div` into my slider and all of them retain a Bootstrap 4 skeleton.
The code would be like this and furthermore it is being generated from another Jquery function in which I am inserting info from a Database. Therefore, I am putting this info into one of each card.

```
  //FUNCIONES
        //Crear especialista
function CrearEspecialistaCard(especialista, mostrarNombreEspecialidad) {
            let cardHTML = "";
            cardHTML += '<div><div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-3 col-md-3 float-left has_border_grey border_10 px-0 overflow-hidden mr-2 profile-box">'
                 + '<div class="card d-inline"><div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 bg-light float-left py-2 text-md-left text-center" style="z-index:101;"> ';
            cardHTML += '<h2 class="text-secondary profile-name">' + ((especialista.sexo == "F") ? "Dra. " : "Dr. ")
                 + especialista.nommed + " " + especialista.apemed + '</h2>' +
                 '<button class="btn btn-secondary btn-profile btn-sm my-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDoctor' + especialista.idEspecialista + '"'
                 +  '>Ver perfil' + '</button>';
            cardHTML += '<h3 class="spec-title">' +  especialista.descesp + '</h3>' + '<h4 class="center-title">' +
                '' + '</h4>'+ '<h5 class="prov-title mb-1">' + especialista.provincias + '</h5>';
             cardHTML += '<p id="reservarCita" class=""> RESERVAR CITA</p>' + 
                (especialista.teleConsulta === true) ? 
                    '<a class="d-inline-block  mr-1" href="/videoConsulta"><img class="bg-purple py-1 px-1" src="/Content/Img/videoconsulta30.png" style="max-width:30px;"  />' +
                    '</a>' : '';
                cardHTML += (especialista.videoConsulta === true) ? 
                    '<a class="d-inline-block mr-1" href="/teleConsulta"><img class="bg-purple-red py-1 px-1" src="/Content/Img/teleconsulta-30.png" style="max-width:30px;" />'  +
                    '</a>' : '';
                cardHTML += (especialista.consulta === true) ? '<a class="d-inline-block  mr-1" href="/pedirCita">' + 
                    '<img class="bg-light-purple py-1 px-1" src="/Content/Img/presencial30.png" style="max-width:30px;"  />' +
                    '</a>' : '';
               cardHTML += '</div>';     
               cardHTML += '  <div class="col-md-6 float-left"  style="z-index:100;">' +
                        '<img class="profile-img img-fluid"  src="/Content/Img/Medicos/CuadroAsistencial/FORMATO-MEDICOS.jpg" alt="Doctor" />' +
                    '</div>';     
                 
            if (mostrarNombreEspecialidad != undefined && mostrarNombreEspecialidad == true) {
                cardHTML += '<br /><span style="font-size:small;" class="colorcard bold">' + especialista.descesp + '</span>';
            } else {
                cardHTML += '<br />';
            }            
            cardHTML += '</div></div></div>';
            return cardHTML;
}
```

I am going to show you where I create the row which inserts one of every card with an anonymous function.

```
   const MuestraEspecialistasFavoritos = (qRow) => {
                let resultadoHTML = "";
                let modalHTML = "";

                resultadoHTML += '<div class="preview-carousel">'; // this is where I generate the class for my carousel
                for (var a = 0; a < globalModeloFavoritos.length; a++) {
                    let toto = ca_model.listaEspecialistas.filter(b => b.idEspecialista == globalModeloFavoritos[a]);
                    if ( toto ) resultadoHTML += CrearEspecialistaCard(toto[0] , false);
                    if( toto )
                     var doctor = toto[0];  
                     modalHTML += loadModal(doctor, toto[0].idEspecialista);
                }
               
                modalesRecientes.html(modalHTML);  
                resultadoHTML += '</div>';
                qRow.html(resultadoHTML);
        }
```

When I already have constructed my cards, which in this case they are functioning and being displayed as I want to, I am calling the slick slider so that I can interpret one of every card as one unique slider.

```
        $('.preview-carousel').slick({
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 1
        });
```

My slick.js is loaded as I already checked but it doesn't do absolutely nothing.
FYI every one of the cards generates a div firstly with no classes and no ids so I can be able to interpret every one of the items as if they were items of the slider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found it already.
It wasn't that hard actually.
I was trying to run the slick function inside a document ready function.
With an on load functions, it works perfectly.

```
  $(window).on('load', function() {
        $('.preview-carousel').slick({
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 1
        });
    });
```